# How to bind multiple tables to single DM form?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a `DM Form` type page, where I would like to show and update values from different tables. By default when I created page, I have been asked for data source, specified only one of the tables, which in fact created process in `After Header` of type `Automated Row Fetch`. Also in `After Submit` a process of type `Automatic Row Processing (DML)` is created. When I add an item in the page from different table, obviously I am getting an error that the column not found in that table. How can I add more tables into that page, so they will be fetched and updated properly?

There is a common column in all tables, to identify which record I would like to show from each table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to show and update values from different tables
>
> [...]
>
> There is a common column in all tables, to identify which record I would like to show from each table.

Maybe are you looking for a simple [`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) on your various tables?

Based on [Oracle's HR example schema](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28328/scripts.htm#Cihgfecd), if you need to display both departments and employees names, you write something *like* that as your report query:

```
SELECT department_name as dep_name,
       first_name || ' ' || last_name as emp_name
FROM HR.DEPARTMENTS JOIN HR.EMPLOYEES
USING(DEPARTMENT_ID)
```

In order for this to be usable from APEX form builder, you have to wrap it in a `VIEW`:

```
CREATE VIEWS MY_VIEW AS SELECT .... FROM ... JOIN ...
```

I can't guarantee that the view will be update-able out-of-the-box as [Oracle has very specific rules for inherently updatable views](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8004.htm#CEGCADFA) -- especially for [join views](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views001.htm#ADMIN11782). However, you might be able to make your view updatable anyway by using an [`INSTEAD OF` trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#LNPLS20041). If you decide to go that way, maybe worth considering asking an other question on that specific topic if needed.

Comment: I would be happy to use JOIN, but there is no place to specify that query in DM form. So I will be looking for more apex related answer.

Comment: @Pablo Sorry, I missed the point of your question: of course you need to wrap your `JOIN` in a `VIEW` in order to be usable from the Apex form builder.

Comment: @Pablo Depending your needs, you might use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger to make your view updatable even in Oracle considers it as _non-inherently updatable_. I've added pointers to some relevant documentation in my answer. Hope this helps you!